# variable not being defined in a class despite being defined in it's init function

Tags: python, wxpython, mysql-python

```
from wx import *
import Customer as c

class CustomerMain ( wx.Frame ):

        def __init__( self, parent ):
            wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Customers", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 517,486 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( -1,-1 ), wx.DefaultSize )

            bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )


            # Create a customer
            self.cust = c.Customer()

            self.list = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LC_ICON )
            self.list.InsertColumn(0,'ID', width = 140)
            self.list.InsertColumn(1,'First Name', width = 140)
            self.list.InsertColumn(2,'Last Name', width = 140)
            self.list.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 500,300 ) )
            self.list.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 1000,800 ) )



            bSizer3.Add( self.list, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

            self.m_button20 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add Customer", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button20.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_entry)
            bSizer4.Add( self.m_button20, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_button21 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Update Record", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button21.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_entry)
            self.refresh_list(None)
            bSizer4.Add( self.m_button21, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )

            bSizer3.Add( bSizer4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
            self.Layout()

            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
            self.Show()

        def refresh_list(self, event):
            """Place the names of each CustomerEntry into the list"""

            index =0
            self.entryDict = {}
            for entry in self.cust.list_entries():
                self.list.InsertStringItem(index,entry.Cust_ID)
                self.list.SetStringItem(index,1,entry.L_Name)
                self.list.SetStringItem(index,2,entry.F_Name)
                index += 1

##            self.list.RefreshItems(self)
        def add_entry(self, event):
           """Add a new entry to the Address cust"""
           # start out with blank, generic CustomerEntry
           entry = c.CustomerEntry("", "", "", "","" )
           self.endiag = CustomerDetail(self , entry)
           self.endiag.Show()

           # now we got details in new_entry, add it
           self.cust.add_entry(entry.Cust_ID,entry.F_Name, entry.L_Name, entry.Address,entry.Cust_Stat)

##           self.refresh_list()

        def show_detail(self, event):
           e_id = int(self.list.curselection()[0])
           entry = self.cust.list_entries()[e_id]
           CustomerDetail(entry)
           self.refresh_list()

def __del__( self ):
    pass


class CustomerDetail ( wx.Dialog ):

        def __init__( self, parent,entry ):
                wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 690,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

                self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 500,500 ), wx.DefaultSize )

                bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

                gSizer6 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

                self.m_staticText5 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ID", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_staticText5.Wrap( -1 )
                gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText5, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

                self.Cust_ID = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.Cust_ID.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
                self.Cust_ID.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

                gSizer6.Add( self.Cust_ID, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

                self.m_staticText6 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"First Name", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_staticText6.Wrap( -1 )
                gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText6, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

                self.F_Name = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.F_Name.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
                self.F_Name.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

                gSizer6.Add( self.F_Name, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

                self.m_staticText7 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Last Name", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_staticText7.Wrap( -1 )
                gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText7, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

                self.L_Name = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.L_Name.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
                self.L_Name.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

                gSizer6.Add( self.L_Name, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

                self.m_staticText8 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Address", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_staticText8.Wrap( -1 )
                gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText8, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

                self.Address = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.Address.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
                self.Address.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

                gSizer6.Add( self.Address, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

                self.m_staticText12 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Status", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_staticText12.Wrap( -1 )
                gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText12, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )


                stat_choices = ["Active","Inactive","Archived"]

                self.Cust_Stat = wx.ComboBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"select option!", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, stat_choices, 0 )
                self.Cust_Stat.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
                self.Cust_Stat.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 300,15 ) )
                self.Cust_Stat.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnSelect)
                gSizer6.Add( self.Cust_Stat, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

                bSizer6.Add( gSizer6, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

                bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

                self.m_button24 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ok", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_button24.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ok)

                bSizer13.Add( self.m_button24, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

                self.m_button25 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
                self.m_button25.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.closeDial)

                bSizer13.Add( self.m_button25, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

                bSizer6.Add( bSizer13, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

                self.SetSizer( bSizer6 )
                self.Layout()

                self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        def OnSelect (self, event):
            self.Cust_Stat.GetValue()

        def closeDial(self,event):
                self.Destroy()


        def ok(self, event):
            self.entry.set_details( str(self.Cust_ID.get()),
                                str(self.F_Name.get()),
                                str(self.L_Name.get()),
                                str(self.Address.get()),
                                str(self.Cust_Stat.get()) )
            self.closeDial

        def __del__( self ):
                pass                
def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    CustomerMain(None)
    ex.MainLoop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So given the code above in the CustomerDetail dialog... at the ok function. It tries to call entry which is a reference to Customer.py where the set_details is found. thing is it claims that it is not defined in the class despite me setting it in the init function and defining it as the handler for the customer object... any ideas?

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\sad pROG\customer_app.py", line 173, in ok 
    self.entry.set_details( str(self.Cust_ID.get()),
AttributeError: 'CustomerDetail' object has no attribute 'entry'
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact stack trace?

Comment: I don't see any line where you set `self.entry`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\sad pROG\customer_app.py", line 173, in ok
    self.entry.set_details( str(self.Cust_ID.get()),
AttributeError: 'CustomerDetail' object has no attribute 'entry'


It's like it's not calling that particular module of the customer.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you passed in `entry` as a parameter to `CustomerDetail.__init__`, but didn't set it on the object.

You'll need to do something like this...

```
class CustomerDetail ( wx.Dialog ):
    def __init__( self, parent,entry ):
        wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 690,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )
        self.entry = entry
        # <rest of code here>
```

...to store the variable as a class attribute, otherwise it'll go out of scope when the `__init__` method ends.